# How exactly do I use gsutil to download a Google Cloud Storage bucket to a local disk?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I am trying to download a full bucket from my Google Cloud Storage. I am using gsutil and the CLOUD SHELL Terminal.

My current piece of code receives and error: "CommandException: Destination URL must name a directory, bucket, or bucket
subdirectory for the multiple source form of the cp command."

The code is:

gsutil -m cp -r gs://googleBucket D:\GOOGLE BACKUP

where googleBucket is the bucket and D:\GOOGLE BACKUP is the directory to my desired download location. Am I missing something here?

Any help is appreciated.
P.S. I am in no way tech savvy, and most of this is new to me.

Comment: Can you check with double quotes  for the windows path `gsutil -m cp -r gs://googleBucket "D:\GOOGLE BACKUP"` ?

Comment: I am a little bit confused. You say you are using Cloud Shell which is Linux based, but also use D:\GOOGLE BACKUP for downloading. And your title mentions you want to download it to local disk. Are you referring to your computer or the VM where Cloud Shell is running?

Comment: Its a 2 part process, hence my answer below

Comment: @ClumsyPuffin same error.

Comment: @p13rr0m I am just as confused as you are. I'm running Windows 10 and am trying to downloading it to my computer. Cloud Shell is what the Google console opens and I'm prompted to paste the code to download there.

Comment: what are you confused about? I put an answer for you.

Comment: Okay, the problem is that you cannot directly download the files to your local computer via gsutil and Cloud Shell. Cloud Shell is running on a VM in the Cloud (in a GCP managed project). So downloading it inside Cloud Shell will only downloading  to VM in the Cloud. If you are working directly in Cloud Shell than this is fine and the solution from @dany L is correct. You can check the success of your download with `ls`. If however you want to download the files to your Windows machine you would have to either use the Cloud Console or install gsutil (the google-cloud-sdk) on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

download this way first

> gsutil -m cp -r gs://googleBucket .

The . downloads it to current directory. Do an `ls` and you will see the download

Then go to the 3 dots and download locally. The 3 dots is to the right of open editor.

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply. When executing that command I receive the error: "[Errno 28] No space left on device". This is why I am trying to directly download it to a specific location, in this case a disk that has enough available space.

Comment: the same thing can be done on compute engine if for whatever reason cloudshell is full, assuming you do not want to delete anything in cloudshell.

Comment: If you have lots of files its is better to go through compute engine